# Java Arrays, finding equal element

Tags: java

If I have two Arrays, one named **rank** and one named **rating**, they both can hold 12 elements.
Rating gets its elements from user inputs(scanner in this case). 
The **rank** array is then gonna take the elements from the **rating** array and rank them from lowest to highest, but if there is two of the same elements in rating, the program should find where in the index the elements are and check what rank those numbers are.

So is there a method or a way, to find what elements are the same and how many that are same?
This is the code at the moment.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int participant = 0;
    int rating[] = new int[12];
    double rank[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};

    String display = "Participant\tRating\t\tRank\n";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

           for(int i=0; i<rating.length; i++){
               participant++;
               System.out.println("Enter rating for participant "+participant+":");
               rating[i] = scan.nextInt();
           }        
            Arrays.sort(rating);
            participant = 1;    
            for(int i=0; i<rank.length; i++){

                display += participant+"\t\t"+rating[i]+"\t\t";    
                if(rating[i] == rating[i]-1 || rating[i] == rating[i]+1){
                        display += (rank[i]+rank[i]-1)/2;
                    }
                    else{
                        display += rank[i];
                    }
                    display+="\n";
                    participant++;
                }
                System.out.println(display);

    }
```

The thing I want is whenever there is two of the same elements in the rating array, it should take the rank numbers at which the equal rating elements are and divide by 2.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: There is always a way to do. Please show what you have tried. And ask us where you stuck or getting error.

Comment: Try something and you'll find that you're closer to solving the problem than you thought :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the first array and put them in a hashmap, the key is the element the value is the count.

If you just wanted to know if it had duplicates you could put them in a set and compare the array and set size.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to check the position in the original array? You can implement a sorting algorithm to order the identical elements in the way you want based off their position in the original array. I would post an example but you havent been clear about how you want to order the identical elements.